# Is anyone else thinking about wrapping the leap for ROS?

Tags: ros, pcl, hand-interaction

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems like it would be really fun in our community!

> The Leap technology is 200 times more
> accurate than anything else on the
> market — at any price point. Just
> about the size of a flash drive, the
> Leap can distinguish your individual
> fingers and track your movements down
> to a 1/100th of a millimeter.

[Company website](http://leapmotion.com/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34575/is-anyone-else-thinking-about-wrapping-the-leap-for-ros?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-22**:
Doesn't look like it has Linux support yet... :(

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-07**:
It does support Linux, however I am not sure what is it ! It is surely NOT OpenNi and they have not yet unveiled their technology. So a ROS port-in may only be possible if one can 'hack-into' the hardware, I was seriously thinking on the lines of using Arduino as a middle level hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just integrated the Leap in ROS. Functionality is limited but you are welcome to fork me on GitHub: https://github.com/warp1337/rosleapmotion

---

Originally posted by [flier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3680/flier/) with karma: 76 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2013-10-23**:
I'm in the process of packaging florian's work, documentation at http://wiki.ros.org/rosleapmotion

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bosch was able to get it working with ROS: See this demo, http://youtu.be/wDEb_0HpgVA  I don't know how they did that. Maybe @dejanpan can advise.

The bigger problem is that I don't know of anyone who has been able to get a leap device yet.  Even Bosch's demo was just done in a weekend hackathon with a loaner device.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-05-17**:
We initially did on MacOS since the leap driver was only available for MacOS and Windows but now meanwhile we also have a Linux driver. Though as Tully said we are still only borrowing the device and we yet have to clarify with Leap Motion if we can release ROS driver. Should be no problem I hope.

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2013-07-25**:
@dejanpan Any news on whether or when you can release the linux driver? We got our leap device and are very eager to play with it in ROS! :)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-13**:
Now the device is available everywhere!

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-08-14**:
+1 to be interested in a ros node, especially one working in Fuerte ;-)